# How to extract data from docker images

Tags: docker

I have pulled a docker image from a serve and I want to extract data from that image.

Is there any command for extracting data from an image?

Comment: what you mean by extracting data from image. Can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A method is to first run your image:

```
docker run -it -d IMAGE:TAG
docker ps
```

and then use [docker cp](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) command:

```
docker cp CONTAINER_ID:/foo.txt foo.txt
```

Also you can copy to image

```
docker cp foo.txt CONTAINER_ID:/foo.txt
```