# Copy files between two docker containers using scp

Tags: docker, ssh, containers, scp

I have created two docker containers named as server and client using alpine image and I am running both containers.
Then I installed `apk add openssh` and `apk add openrc` in both the containers.
Using `rc-service sshd start` I have started the ssh service.
Now, I want to copy a file using `scp`.

From server container I typed:

```
scp myfile.txt client@172.17.0.3:/location_of_the_folder
```

It is asking a password for the client container.
What can I do?
What is the default password for docker container(s)?

I have tried 3 options as follows:

1. Attach the same volume to both the containers.
2. Using `docker cp` from server container to host and then host to
   client container.
3. Using `ssh-keygen` in the server container and copied the `id_rsa.pub`
   key manually to client containers `/root/.ssh` directory and it works.

I don't want to use options 1 and 2.
What should I do for option 3 using shell script? I want to automate this thing.
I can do it manually, but can we do it by automation using a shell script, to copy some text from one container to another container?

Comment: use `docker cp`

Comment: @LinPy, using `scp` instead of `docker cp` is required if the docker is running on a different host, not locally.

Answer (score 9):

If it's a local docker container, use **docker cp** as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57589347/7101368):

`docker cp {container_name}:{file_path} {target_file_path OR target_dir_ended_with_slash}`

But if you really need `ssh` (e.g. when container runs in a remote host), try these steps:

**1.** Make sure you run your container with ssh port 22 redirection from host, e.g. `docker run -p 8022:22 ...`

Then inside the container:

**2.** **Install sshd**: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y openssh-server`

**3.** Create sshd directory: `mkdir /var/run/sshd`

**4.** **Add password** to current user ("root" user doesn't have password by default): `passwd`

**5.** Set **`PermitRootLogin yes`** in sshd_config: `sudo sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

**6.** You might also need: `sudo sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd`

**7.** And: `sudo sh -c 'echo "export VISIBLE=now" >> /etc/profile'`

**8.** **Restart sshd** service: `sudo service ssh restart`

Then you should be able to connect with SSH, and transfer files with SCP.

If you get "**port 22: Connection refused**", try any of these workarounds:

- Run container with privileged access: `docker exec --privileged -ti container_name bash`
- Inside container, open port 22 with UFW firewall: `sudo apt-get install -y ufw && sudo ufw allow 22`

Comment: I did it... but again it will ask me for a password of the server/client container.

Comment: Modify `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, not `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`. I've tested as I describe and I could connect successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the Docker Linux distribution base images have all passwords disabled for all users.  Also, the setup you're describing has a lot of credentials to manage (in each image, your local user's password, the remote user's password, your own ssh host keys, the remote ssh host keys) and doing this securely is tricky.  (For instance, if you set a password in your `Dockerfile`, then anyone who has the image can read it out of `docker history` or try to crack the hashed password from the image's `/etc/shadow` file.)

I would suggest avoiding ssh in Docker.  It avoids the credential issues shown above, and also avoids the intrinsic difficulties in running more than one process in a container.

The easiest approach here is to add an endpoint to the "server" that can produce the file content, and have the "client" request it on startup or when it needs it.

You can also mount the same named Docker volume or host directory into both containers, and both will have read-write access to the same files, so you can transfer files this way.  It's usually not a concern but there are potential race conditions (the same as if you were running both on the same system without Docker).  This approach also doesn't scale well to multi-host installations like Docker Swarm or Kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you would use `docker cp`. But if you still want to use **scp** (and perhaps **rsync**) for testing purposes here are the steps that worked for me:

**1.** copy `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` to your working directory

**2.** Create a **Dockerfile** in this directory, it will use the aforementioned `authorized_keys`:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server rsync

RUN apt-get clean

# Create the missing directory for privilege separation
RUN mkdir -p /run/sshd

COPY ./authorized_keys /root/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Expose the SSH server port
EXPOSE 22

# Configure SSH to allow key-based authentication and disable password authentication
RUN echo "PermitRootLogin yes" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN echo "PasswordAuthentication no" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN echo "PubkeyAuthentication yes" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config

CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

Note that since we are creating the image for testing purposes, I've **disabled password** and permitted Root Login.

**3.** Define the following `docker-compose.yml` file (note that I'm using docker-compose for convenience, you can build an image without it)

```
version: '3'
services:
  ssh-container:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: ssh-container
    ports:
      - "2222:22"  # Map host port 2222 to container port 22
```

**4.** run docker compose, e.g. you can use `docker-compose up -d` to run it in a detached mode.

Now you can use **scp** command like so:

`scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -P 2222 local_file_path root@localhost:/path/on/docker/container`

and **rsync** command like so:

`rsync -Pav -e 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' -p 2222, local_file_path, root@localhost:/path/on/docker/container`

I'm using the `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` flag here because on every docker run its host keys will change and SSH clients will raise a *REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED* warning.